# Conditional Listener in manifest v3 background service worker

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Is it possible to have a listener in a conditional in MV3 background service worker or do listeners have to be on top-level?

e.g.

```js
// "service_worker": "background.js"

if (condition) {
  chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(handleActionClick);
}

// subsequent to comment by wOxxOm, for example
if (typeof browser !== 'undefined') {
  browser.proxy.onRequest.addListener(onRequest, {urls: ['<all_urls>']});
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible if `condition` is determined synchronously. You can also register listeners inside other functions that are executed synchronously.

Comment: @wOxxOm yes... the condition is synchronous e.g. `if (typeof browser !== 'undefined')`

Comment: @wOxxOm What happens to a listeners that is in a synchronous `class` but imported with `import` in the background service worker?

Comment: It works as well in my tests. Apparently all import *statements* finish in the first event loop cycle, although I didn't read the specification about that.

Comment: @wOxxOm Many thanks indeed for the help.

Answer (score -1):

it would be better that you put the linester on top-level.
Otherwise there is a serious risk that the SW will not be awakened by that event.

You could move the condition into the handler (handleActionClick), can't you?