# Avoid repeated storage calls in manifest v3 service worker listener

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Considering a situation where network connections have to be processed based on user-set criteria, in MV2 with persistent background script, criteria can be cached to avoid repeated calls to the storage.

AFA I understand, that would not be possible in MV3.

Is there an alternative/better way to avoid repeated calls to the storage?

For example:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(onRequest, {urls: ['<all_urls>']});

function onRequest(requestInfo) {
  /*   
    process
    ------------------
    1. get user preferences asynchronously e.g.
    await chrome.storage.local.get();

    2. loop through all criteria
    3. convert all patterns to RegExp
    4. check if they match the criteria
    5. prepare a process
    6. repeat the same for each request
  */
}
```

*Note: Above listener is only an example and the question mainly relates to the caching of the storage data.*

---

**Update** based on reply by wOxxOm
Would the following work?

```js
// cache
let cache;

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(onRequest, {urls: ['<all_urls>']});

function onRequest(requestInfo) {
  /*   
    process
    ------------------
    1. check if cache is set
    if (!cache) {
      await prepareCache();
    }
    
    2. check if they match the criteria in cache
    3. prepare a process
    4. repeat the same for each request
  */
}

async function prepareCache() {
  /* 
    1. get user preferences asynchronously e.g.
    await chrome.storage.local.get();

    2. convert all patterns to RegExp
    3. save to cache 
  */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently MV3 is bugged so it won't even wake up the worker for webRequest, see [workarounds](/q/66618136/).

As for storage, you only need to read it once per waking up: [example](/a/73090402). It'll happen quite rarely if you you use the above workaround named *"Persistent" service worker while a connectable tab is present*.

I also suggest using IndexedDB because it can store RegExp object directly so that your code won't lose a lot of time to recompile them. IndexedDB API is callback-based but there are simple Promise-based libraries around, and writing one yourself is easy enough.

Comment: Thank you wOxxOm. I have updated the post. Would that work?

Comment: Yes, it's essentially the same as the example I've linked.

Comment: BTW, Is IndexedDB available in MV3 background Service Worker? There is no `window` object ( same case as `localStorage` etc)

Comment: Yes. You can replace it with `self` or `globalThis` but there's no need for `window` object, you can use any global property directly e.g.  `indexedDB`.

Comment: Thank you wOxxOm. BTW, did you see my question in the comments in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73364243/conditional-listener-in-manifest-v3-background-service-worker ?

Answer (score 0):

Do we really need to worry about this? Isn't the WebExtension browser code going to cache frequently-accessed storage in memory anyway (making calls to storage actually calls to some in-memory cache structure)

Comment: chrome.storage is very slow in Chrome, slower than any other local storage, especially with large amounts of data. The implementation of the API itself is slow, not the physical disk access.